# Using Razor, how do I make all "bool?" properties appear as Yes/No/Not Set on details pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Here's my page code so far:

```
@model TennisClub.Models.ClubMember
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}
<h2>
    Details
</h2>
<fieldset>
    <legend>ClubMember</legend>
    @Html.DisplayForModel()
</fieldset>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.Id }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

For all the nullable bools (`bool?`) in my model, this displays a dimmed select list with either Not Set, True, or False. I'd like it to be just plain text: either Not Set, Yes, or No.

How can I achieve this most easily? I'd like this style to be global throughout my site.

**Edit**

Just took a stab at making a template per Mark's answer, but the details page looks exactly the same.

I created a bool.cshtml file and placed it in the following folder:

> [ProjectFolder]/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates

Here's what I have for my **bool.cshtml** template at the moment:

```
@model bool?

@if (Model == null)
{
    <text>Not Set</text>
}
else
{
    if (Model.Value)
    {
        <text>Yes</text>
    }
    else
    {
        <text>No</text>
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to have any affect on my details pages at all.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit 2**

Here's my model class:

```
public class ClubMember
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string PhoneType { get; set; }
    public bool? CanPlayDays { get; set; }
    public bool? CanPlayEvenings { get; set; }
    public bool? CanPlayWeekends { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the template that is rendering the model field?  Also, what does your model file look like?

Comment: @Mark S., there is no template for the model field...I'm just using `DisplayForModel()` as shown at the top of my question. As for the model class, I'll paste that in.

Comment: See @iaimtomisbehave comment below.  I was mistaken with the name of the file.  If that works, I will update my answer so it doesn't confuse anyone else.

Comment: @Mark S., I just edited your answer myself and marked it the answer. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would want to override the default template.  In short, under your views folder, you would create a "DisplayTemplates" folder and a "EditorTemplates" folder.  Once you have this, you can create a `Boolean.cshtml` file in each one where the Model is `bool?`.  Then you can do what ever you want as far as display options go.  This will change how all `bool?` model fields render.

Here is a blog post that I have refered to many times to help me figure this out.  http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html

UPDATE: One word of caution, remember to handle the `null` case.  I have forgotten to do that in the past and it had bitten me.

Comment: Hey Mark, Thanks for your answer. I gave it a try, but so far no luck. If you have a minute, could you please see my edit to my question?

Comment: @DanM try renaming bool.cshtml to Boolean.cshtml.

Answer (score 6):

The template file is the way to go for site wide implementation. But I'd take it a step further with an extension method.

```
public static string ToString(this bool? b, string ifTrue, string ifFalse, string ifNull)
{
   if(!b.HasValue) return ifNull;
   return b.Value ? ifTrue : ifFalse;
}
Boolean.ToString("Yes","No","Not Set");
```

This allows easier display of arbitrary values.