# Html.DisplayFor with boolean value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Why does `@Html.DisplayFor()` with a boolean value display either a disabled checkbox or disabled select (depending on nullable or not) insead of true/false/nothing?

With a string, for instance, I don't get a disabled textbox.. I get the value. Why the difference?

Comment: Because the library authors have determined that a disabled checkbox is the "right" way to display a boolean in a web page. I for one do not agree, then again they're the ones writing the library, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, because a `checkbox` doesn't need to be *culture-dependent*: you don't have to translate true/false/nothing in every possible language. So it's much more easy for the library authors to maintain...etc.

That being said, you can of course override this default behavior. See for example [Using Razor, how do I make all "bool?" properties appear as Yes/No/Not Set on details pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783505/using-razor-how-do-i-make-all-bool-properties-appear-as-yes-no-not-set-on-de)